# Does AWS Sagemaker charges you per API request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

AWS pricing page describes how much it costs per hour to run AWS Sagemaker for online realtime inference.
https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/pricing/

But AWS usually also charges for API requests.
Do they charge extra per every API inference request to the Sagemaker model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am on the AWS SageMaker team.  For "Real-Time Inference" you are only charged for:

1. usage of the instance types you choose (instance hours)
2. storage attached to those instance (GB storage hours)
3. data in and out of your Endpoint (Bytes in/out)

See "Pricing Example #6: Real-Time Inference" as well.