# Does AWS charge more for running multiple Jupyter notebooks on one Sagemaker Notebook instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook, architecture, amazon-sagemaker

1. Does AWS charge more for running multiple Jupyter notebooks on one Sage maker Notebook instance?

According to https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/pricing/ :

> "You are charged for the instance type you choose, based on the duration of use"

Does this include the time of multiple notebooks running at the same time?
So if 3 notebooks ran for 40 minutes simultaneously would it charge the same as 1 notebook running for 120 minutes?

According to this post: [Does AWS Sagemaker charges you per API request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64684503/does-aws-sagemaker-charges-you-per-api-request) aws charges based on 3 things:

1. Usage of the instance types you choose (instance hours)
2. Storage attached to those instance (GB storage hours)
3. Data in and out of your Endpoint (Bytes in/out)

So:
2. How does AWS charge for storage within the Jupyter Notebook instance?

3. How does AWS charge for *"data in and out of your Endpoint (Bytes in/out)"*

Answer (score 1):

Check [SageMaker pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/pricing/) here after clicking the `On-Demand Notebook Instances` tab.

> How does AWS charge for storage within the Jupyter Notebook instance?

You're charged by the size of the EBS volume (GB/Month) you choose to attach to the notebook instance.

> How does AWS charge for "data in and out of your Endpoint (Bytes in/out)"

This is a cost type is associated with realtime endpoints that host a model, and is not related to notebook instances.
With notebook instances you're networking cost is similar to an EC2 instance (free within the same availability zone and VPC and to regional S3. And incur cost for inter-AZ, inter-region, and outgoing Internet traffic).